# How can I add new rows from a dataframe to another one based on key column

Tags: python, pandas, data-wrangling

My df1 is something like first table in the below image with the key column being Name. I want to add new rows from another dataframe, df2, which has only Name, Year, and Value columns. The new rows should get added based on Name.  Other columns would just repeat the same value per Name.  Results should be similar to the second table in the below image. How can I do this in pandas ?

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] people can work with instead of text only.

Answer (score 0):

Create a sub table df3 of df1 consist of Group, Name, and Other and only keep distinct records. And left join df2 and df3 to get desired result.